# Data migration with knex.js is giving violates check constraint error when performing batchInsert

Tags: node.js, express, knex.js, objection.js

In my express app there are two tables:

- documents
- document_revision_fields

I need to migrate some of the columns of some of the records (based on the value of one of the columns) inside the *document_revision_fields* to a new table *document_fields*.

This is how the new table is being created:

```js
await knex.schema
    .createTable('document_fields', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table
        .text('sid')
        .unique()
      table.text('applicationId')
      table
        .foreign('applicationId')
        .references('id')
        .inTable('applications')
        .onDelete('CASCADE')
      table.text('documentId')
      table
        .foreign('documentId')
        .references('id')
        .inTable('documents')
        .onDelete('CASCADE')
      table.text('digitalAssetId')
      table
        .foreign(['digitalAssetId', 'applicationId'])
        .references(['id', 'applicationId'])
        .inTable('digital_assets')
        .onDelete('CASCADE')
      table.enu('type', ['text', 'embed', 'slideshow'])
      table.text('value')
      table.text('copy')
      table.text('header')
      table.enu('status', ['active', 'inactive', 'deleted'])
      table.integer('order')
      table.text('meta')
      table.timestamp('createdAt').defaultTo(knex.fn.now())
      table.timestamp('updatedAt').defaultTo(knex.fn.now())
    })
```

This is how I'm selecting the rows to be migrated

```js
  const rows = await knex('document_revision_fields')
    .select(
      'document_revision_fields.sid',
      'document_revision_fields.applicationId',
      'document_revision_fields.documentId',
      'document_revision_fields.digitalAssetId',
      'document_revision_fields.type',
      'document_revision_fields.value',
      'document_revision_fields.copy',
      'document_revision_fields.header',
      'document_revision_fields.status',
      'document_revision_fields.order',
      'document_revision_fields.meta'
    )
    .join('documents', 'documents.activeRevisionId', 'document_revision_fields.revisionId')
```

And finally, this is how I'm trying to migrate these rows to the new table

```js
return knex.batchInsert('document_fields', rows)
```

Everything up until the *batchInsert* does work. In fact I can console.log the *rows* variable and I get the expected result.

When I try to batchInsert these rows in the new table, however, I get this error

```
Failed to migrate schema.
error: new row for relation "document_fields" violates check constraint "document_fields_type_check"
detail: "Failing row contains (52808, Nmw-5qMsV, 06217620-aee9-11e9-9f1a-4bff6f1a2985, f046adc0-3214-11ea-8056-31c443663220, null, paragraph, <p>Here's President Donald Trump's tweet for reference.&nbsp;</p..., null, null, active, 5, {}, 2020-05-21 07:20:24.022705+02, 2020-05-21 07:20:24.022705+02)."
```

Can you spot any issue at all?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you have set up `type` to be an enum:

```js
table.enu('type', ['text', 'embed', 'slideshow'])
```

However, you are trying to insert either `null` or `paragraph`, and neither of them are part of the enum.

Comment: Thanks for your input Mika! That was sorta related and ended up putting me on the right track.

This was a client projects that I had just started working on and thus didn't have much visibility of the past changes. Turns out there was a custom postgres CHECK added to the origin table that needed to be replicated.

Thad did the trick.